# How to add a print output (response body - JSON or Text) in cucumber reports using Karate DSL?

Tags: karate

How to add a print output (response body - JSON or Text) in cucumber reports using Karate DSL ?. Also attaching a file so that that can be viewed in report.

Currently only Docstg is displayed in cucumber report.

Helpfull if any sample is provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for how to integrate the Cucumber-Reporting plugin that should give you what you need, and there are sample screenshots: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

And if you use the `print` statement, that output also appears in the log, which can be JSON or XML. Note that the `print` statement can do 'pretty printing'.

In my opinion, there is no need for extra attachments and there is no support for that right now.

Comment: Thanks. After switching to 0.7 version - print output is appearing. But if there is option to add attachment (like screen ref) would be better as some cases we invoke Selenium.

Comment: ok I have added this point to this enhancement request, thanks ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444